# How to restore data base using InfluxD

Tags: backup, influxdb

I am using influxd and have created the back up using

```
influxd backup -database grpcdb /opt/data
```

I can see that files are created under /opt/data directory

Now, i want to restore same datafiles with different database name on same machine.

```
influxd restore -database grpcdb1 /opt/data
```

but getting below mention error

```
restore: -datadir is required to restore
```

Here i am providing same data path. Not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way for doing that.

Important thing:

Data can only by exported when Influxdb instance is running.
Data can only be imported when Influxdb instance is **not** running.

Export data:

```
sudo service influxdb start (Or leave this step if service is already running)
influxd backup -database grpcdb /opt/data
```

Import Data:

```
sudo service influxdb stop
influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta /opt/data
influxd restore -database grpcdb -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data /opt/data
sudo service influxdb start
```

Comment: what if when I am running influxdb as a docker container, then how am I suppose to run influxd restore command if I stopped running influxdb container.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data

Don't forget to restore metadata first as Ammad wrote.